# Display day of year in cobol

Tags: cobol

I'm trying to display the day of the year in cobolol but it doesn't work. this code doesn't display anything and I can't figure out why. Can anyone help me, please?

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. SAMPLE.
   DATA DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01 T-MOFYEAR.
     05 T-M-LINE OCCURS 12.
       10 T-EL-MN         PIC 9(2).
```

Here I take the value of year month and day

```
   01 YEAR                PIC 9(4) VALUE 2017. 
   01 MONTH               PIC 9(2) VALUE 01.
   01 DAYY                PIC 9(2) VALUE 04.
   01 I                   PIC 9(2).
   01 MN                  PIC 9(2).
   01 DOFY                PIC 9(3).

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   MAIN SECTION.
   MAINA.
       PERFORM INIT
       PERFORM
       VARYING I
       FROM 1 BY 1
       UNTIL I = MONTH 
       PERFORM LEAP
       END-PERFORM
       .
   MAINZ.
       STOP RUN.
```

Here I init the month of the year

```
   INIT SECTION.
   INITA.
       MOVE 31               TO T-EL-MN(1)
       MOVE 28               TO T-EL-MN(2)
       MOVE 31               TO T-EL-MN(3)
       MOVE 30               TO T-EL-MN(4)
       MOVE 31               TO T-EL-MN(5)
       MOVE 30               TO T-EL-MN(6)
       MOVE 31               TO T-EL-MN(7)
       MOVE 31               TO T-EL-MN(8)
       MOVE 30               TO T-EL-MN(9)
       MOVE 31               TO T-EL-MN(10)
       MOVE 30               TO T-EL-MN(11)
       MOVE 31               TO T-EL-MN(12)
       .
   INITZ.
       EXIT.
```

Here I check if the year is a leap

```
   LEAP SECTION.
   LEAPA.
       EVALUATE TRUE                                  
           WHEN FUNCTION MOD (YEAR 4)   NOT ZERO    
           WHEN FUNCTION MOD (YEAR 100)     ZERO    
           AND FUNCTION MOD (YEAR 400) NOT ZERO    
           ADD T-EL-MN(I), DAYY TO DOFY
           DISPLAY "DAY OF YEAR = " DOFY
           WHEN OTHER                                      
           DISPLAY 'IT IS A LEAP YEAR     ' YEAR
           MOVE 29 TO T-EL-MN(2)
           ADD T-EL-MN(I), DAYY TO DOFY
           DISPLAY "DAY OF YEAR = " DOFY
        END-EVALUATE      
       .
   LEAPZ.
       EXIT.
```

Comment: 2nd `WHEN` should be `AND`.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't display anything because you told it to never `DISPLAY` anything. See explanation in the appendix.

The possible solution to fix this code part may be to change the code to

```
UNTIL I > MONTH
```

---

And in general it is likely a good idea to check your compiler for support of

```
01 small-yd.
   05 syd-year pic 9(02).
   05 syd-day  pic 9(03).
01 full-yd.
   05 fyd-year pic 9(04).
   05 fyd-day  pic 9(03).

ACCEPT small-yd FROM DAY
ACCEPT full-yd  FROM DAY YYYYDDD
```

---

Appendix: No `DISPLAY` because:

```
01 MONTH               PIC 9(2) VALUE 01.

   PERFORM
   VARYING I
   FROM 1 BY 1
   UNTIL I = MONTH 
   PERFORM LEAP
   END-PERFORM
```

equals

```
   PERFORM
   VARYING I
   FROM 1 BY 1
   UNTIL I = 1
```

equals

```
   PERFORM
   UNTIL 1 = 1
```

equals

```
MAIN SECTION.
MAINA.
   PERFORM INIT
   .
MAINZ.
   STOP RUN.
```

and there is no `DISPLAY` in `INIT SECTION`.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to display the day of the year in [cobol](/questions/tagged/cobol), isn't it much easier to use something like:

```cobol
...
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01  TESTDATE PIC 9(8).

...
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
MAIN SECTION.
MOVE FUNCTION CURRENT-DATE (1:8) TO TESTDATE.            
COMPUTE TESTDATE = FUNCTION DAY-OF-INTEGER(              
                  FUNCTION INTEGER-OF-DATE(TESTDATE) 
               ).                                    
DISPLAY "DAY OF YEAR " TESTDATE (6:3).
...
```

AFAIK these intrinsic functions are available at all cobol compilers.